# Rewarded video ad is not loading

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I am implementing Rewarded video ads in my app. When i try to load rewarded video ad it calls `onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad` method every time and printing some error in the console.Below is my console response.

I successfully done Admob with Firebase integration. I implemented Rewarded video ads with the help of `com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.4` sdk.

```
05-23 14:24:18.787 671-1492/com.app.adme E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Internal track renderer error.
                                                                  com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer1.d: com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer1.upstream.o: Unable to connect to https://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id=XfMxh24eBkU&ts=1495528753&t=T1S3FU7_OlRsC59YBvaIxTL7jO8&gad=1
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer1.q.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:253)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer1.j.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:2116)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                      at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer1.util.i.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:40)
                                                                   Caused by: com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer1.upstream.o: Unable to connect to https://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id=XfMxh24eBkU&ts=1495528753&t=T1S3FU7_OlRsC59YBvaIxTL7jO8&gad=1
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer1.upstream.h.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:187)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer1.upstream.i.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:151)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay.exoplayer1.r.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:91)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer1.extractor.h.c(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:608)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer1.upstream.t.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:242)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
                                                                   Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x6a677eb8: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
                                                                  error:14077102:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unsupported protocol (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:714 0x5ec5f6fd:0x00000000)
                                                                      at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:448)
                                                                      at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:146)
                                                                      at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:107)
                                                                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
                                                                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
                                                                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
                                                                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
                                                                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
                                                                      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:161)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer1.upstream.h.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:1335)
                                                                        ... 9 more
                                                                   Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x6a677eb8: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
                                                                  error:14077102:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unsupported protocol (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:714 0x5ec5f6fd:0x00000000)
                                                                      at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:405)
                                                                        ... 18 more
05-23 14:24:18.787 671-671/com.app.adme W/Ads: ExoPlayer failed during precache: PlayerError Exception: com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer1.upstream.o: Unable to connect to https://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id=XfMxh24eBkU&ts=1495528753&t=T1S3FU7_OlRsC59YBvaIxTL7jO8&gad=1
05-23 14:24:18.789 671-1494/com.app.adme D/dalvikvm: threadid=68: exiting
05-23 14:24:18.790 671-1494/com.app.adme D/dalvikvm: threadid=68: bye!
05-23 14:24:18.842 671-847/com.app.adme W/Ads: Failed to preload url https://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id=XfMxh24eBkU&ts=1495528753&t=T1S3FU7_OlRsC59YBvaIxTL7jO8&gad=1 Exception: Abort requested before buffering finished. 
05-23 14:24:18.843 671-671/com.app.adme D/WebView: evaluateJavascript=(window.AFMA_ReceiveMessage || function() {})('onPrecacheEvent',{"cachedSrc":"cache:5D0F33814476AAC23895899F54683F67","message":"ExoPlayer caching failed. Type: PlayerError","src":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/get_video?video_id=XfMxh24eBkU&ts=1495528753&t=T1S3FU7_OlRsC59YBvaIxTL7jO8&gad=1","type":"network","reason":"badUrl","event":"precacheCanceled"});
05-23 14:24:18.874 671-925/com.app.adme D/WebViewCallback: shouldInterceptRequest=https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/conversion/?ai=CqS7oMPUjWaapOI2koAPN6bToCPiQ17pJ2tjtq6EF5Kvp5bgBEAEgjbGDN2Dl6uMDoAHkyducA6gDAcgDCKoEhwFP0PiBEO4ptgn27PrV-Vjp80DyHE-drpeKiH7ZE7bfidl_OFjBbQt0SlyYKogFGFIGLh3HuTJp8mqt0yiT0bXklZt-LvCE07yez_QiFam10R6bDWBDYHOih-Oru9Uau9XGfx8s8CWKxODk-Os6uC3162iZ6k0ha_eezdXJtrFrRQO18jKVM8nABNHg68yfAYgF-L3G-QKQBgGgBhywBgGAB4S2pGOYBwGoB6a-G7gH6qPEgs2enaMbwAeL1QPAB-jUA9gHAfoHIWNvbS50YXA0ZnVuLmdhbGF4eWVtcGlyZTJfYW5kcm9pZJgIAaAI_I2pBLAIArgIAdIIBQiAYRABsQlG4q03yjR-ergTsQOCFBsaGW1vYmlsZWFwcDo6Mi1jb20uYXBwLmFkbWU&sigh=AaCPhcw9Wo0&cmd=ChtjYS1hcHAtcHViLTgyNjE2ODYxMTI2NTA2OTQQsQMYAQ&label=videoplayfailed400
05-23 14:24:18.876 671-671/com.app.adme D/WebViewCallback: onLoadResource=https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/conversion/?ai=CqS7oMPUjWaapOI2koAPN6bToCPiQ17pJ2tjtq6EF5Kvp5bgBEAEgjbGDN2Dl6uMDoAHkyducA6gDAcgDCKoEhwFP0PiBEO4ptgn27PrV-Vjp80DyHE-drpeKiH7ZE7bfidl_OFjBbQt0SlyYKogFGFIGLh3HuTJp8mqt0yiT0bXklZt-LvCE07yez_QiFam10R6bDWBDYHOih-Oru9Uau9XGfx8s8CWKxODk-Os6uC3162iZ6k0ha_eezdXJtrFrRQO18jKVM8nABNHg68yfAYgF-L3G-QKQBgGgBhywBgGAB4S2pGOYBwGoB6a-G7gH6qPEgs2enaMbwAeL1QPAB-jUA9gHAfoHIWNvbS50YXA0ZnVuLmdhbGF4eWVtcGlyZTJfYW5kcm9pZJgIAaAI_I2pBLAIArgIAdIIBQiAYRABsQlG4q03yjR-ergTsQOCFBsaGW1vYmlsZWFwcDo6Mi1jb20uYXBwLmFkbWU&sigh=AaCPhcw9Wo0&cmd=ChtjYS1hcHAtcHViLTgyNjE2ODYxMTI2NTA2OTQQsQMYAQ&label=videoplayfailed400
05-23 14:24:19.015 671-671/com.app.adme D/WebView: evaluateJavascript=(window.AFMA_ReceiveMessage || function() {})('volume',{"app_volume":"1.0","device_volume":"1.0","app_muted":"false"});
05-23 14:24:19.015 671-671/com.app.adme D/WebView: onPause
05-23 14:24:19.015 671-671/com.app.adme W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
05-23 14:24:19.026 671-671/com.app.adme W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3
05-23 14:24:19.077 671-671/com.app.adme D/GraphicBuffer: create handle(0x6a68ff50) (w:512, h:88, f:1)
05-23 14:24:21.037 671-671/com.app.adme D/GraphicBuffer: close handle(0x6a68ff50) (w:512 h:88 f:1)
05-23 14:24:21.134 671-793/com.app.adme D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: graph.facebook.com get result from proxy >>
05-23 14:24:21.135 671-793/com.app.adme I/System.out: propertyValue:false
05-23 14:24:21.135 671-793/com.app.adme I/System.out: [socket][64] connection graph.facebook.com/31.13.78.13:443;LocalPort=37657(0)
05-23 14:24:21.136 671-793/com.app.adme I/System.out: [CDS]connect[graph.facebook.com/31.13.78.13:443] tm:90
05-23 14:24:21.137 671-793/com.app.adme D/Posix: [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.app.adme :443 
05-23 14:24:21.268 671-793/com.app.adme I/System.out: [socket][/10.10.5.7:37657] connected
05-23 14:24:21.268 671-793/com.app.adme I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:0
```

Answer (score 2):

I had almost similar error

> Internal track renderer error.
>   Unable to connect to https://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id=XfMxh24eBkU&ts=1495528753&t=T1S3FU7_OlRsC59YBvaIxTL7jO8&gad=1
>   Failed to load ad: 0
>   Failed to load ad: 3

My situation was when I implemented 10.2.6, everything was fine.

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.6'
}
```

But when implemented 11.0.0, the mentioned errors are being displayed.

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.0'
}
```

The solution I had now is to keep 10.2.6 until they have a fix.

---

### Updated - Firebase 11.0.2:

With the updated firebase 11.0.2, the test ads is working as usual.

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.2'
}
```

---